# Java mappedByteBuffer and flip() and position()

Tags: java, buffer, nio

I have some questions on `java.nio.Buffer`. Basically, my question starts with if a `flip()` call is always needed to switch between read and write, or is it only needed for slow I/O, e.g. in the case of write then read, to ensure the data are completely written before they are read. My particular question is with mappedByteBuffer. It looks like if the file exists and is of the size that I know, I can just use the `position(int newPosition)` call to navigate to any part of the file, and perform read or write, i.e. basically use the buffer as a chunk of memory forgetting about the concepts of mark or limit. Is this true?

Consider the following example. If I have a file that contains integer 1, then 2 from the beginning, it seems I can put another integer 3 at position 0, the rewind and read 3 and 2 out from the buffer. Shouldn't the limit stop me from the second getInt like in a normal non-mmap buffer? When do I ever need to call flip() to switch between a write and read of a mappedByteBuffer? Thanks!

```
final int FILESIZE = 1024;

RandomAccessFile fileHandle;
    FileChannel fileChannel;
    File testFile = new File("c:/temp/testbbrw.dat");
    fileHandle = new RandomAccessFile(testFile, "rw");

    fileChannel = fileHandle.getChannel();
    MappedByteBuffer mbb = fileChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, FILESIZE);

    int pos, data;

    mbb.position(0);
    mbb.putInt(3);

    mbb.position(0);
    data=mbb.getInt();  //I get 3
    data=mbb.getInt();  //I get 2, which was written to the file before this program runs

    mbb.force();
    fileHandle.close();
```

Comment: is it possible, that there is more than one 2 in the file before you run the program? sorry, should read first :) you overwrite the 1 in the file with the 3, the limit is the size of the MappedByteBuffer, which is the size of the file.

Answer (score 2):

This is what Buffer.flip does

```
347    public final Buffer flip() {
348        limit = position;
349        position = 0;
350        mark = -1;
351        return this;
352    }
```

It is preparing the buffer, so that the next read operations on the buffer start at position 0 and end at the current limit. means you tell it, that you are done with changing the buffer and ready to move or copy it somewhere else (which means reading it)

Comment: The purpose of `flip()` is to prepare the buffer for *writing*. Read after flip makes no sense.

Comment: @EJP: You are confusing "reading" from a buffer, with "writing" to a channel using that buffer. When a channel *write* operation occurs, it *reads* from a buffer. When a channel *read* operation occurs it *writes* to a buffer. It is best to keep terminology from the perspective of the buffer when conversing about buffers (and yes, I know the JavaDoc makes the same confusion conflation; that doesn't mean you should). I've read a number of your comments on related answers today, and the same confusion is evident in all of them.

Comment: @LawrenceDol The only confusion here us that you are using 'read' when you mean 'put', and 'write' when you mean 'get'. I am looking at the buffer from the point of view of the channel, and in terms of reads and written by the channel, which is why I am using those terms.

Comment: @EJP: That is precisely my point; you are expressing yourself from the point of view of a *channel* when talking about a *buffer*. The channel uses the inverse terminology. Which is confusing when talking about buffers. In common parlance, read = get and write = put. Therefore, `flip()` does ***not*** prepare the buffer for writing, it prepares it for get/read *from the buffer*. Don't discuss one object's methods in terms of another object's methods -- it's *confusing*.

Answer (score 0):

> my question starts with if a flip() call is always needed to switch between read and write, or is it only needed for slow I/O, e.g. in the case of write then read, to ensure the data are completely written before they are read.

1. A `Buffer` of any description starts out in a state where you can read into it, or put to it, which is the same thing.
2. `flip()` puts it into a state where you can write from it, or get from it, which is the same thing.
3. Despite its (extremely stupid) name, `flip()` is not the inverse of `flip()`. Its only inverses are `compact()` and `clear()`.

For clarity I find it best to always leave a `Buffer` in the readable state, and only flip it into the writable state when I need to, and get it back to readable immediately afterwards.

This is for I/O.

If you are doing just `get()` and `put()` I'm not sure I would use `flip()` at all, and as this is a `MappedByteBuffer` I certainly wouldn't be calling `clear()` or `compact()`, both of which could do terrible things to the file, and which also rules out using `flip()`.

Comment: I found this feedback informative, so upvoted.  Thanks :).

Comment: @EJP: My guess about the downvotes is the phrases "read into it" and "write from it", which are wholly confusing and contradictory given the normal semantics programmers typically use. One reads **from** something and writes **to** something. I *think* I know what you mean, but I had to read it a few times, and even now I'm not certain.

Answer (score 0):

The design of the `Buffer` API in Java is confusing and counter-intuitive compared to a typical cyclic, finite buffer. Making things worse is poor choice of terms in the documentation, compounded by equivocal uses of read/write and put/get terms, the former referring to an external operation (typically by a `Channel`) ***using*** a `Buffer`, and the latter to operations ***provided by*** a `Buffer`.

#### Java Buffers

On creation, a new buffer is "empty", ready to be filled. It may be immediately supplied with some content in the constructor, but it remains in the "filling" state.

The `flip()` method "flips" the logical state of the buffer from being filled to being emptied. Rather idiotically `flip()` does not reverse itself, even though in normal English it would usually describe a logically reversible action. Indeed, looking at the code, calling it twice without an intervening `clear` or `compact` sets the buffer into an invalid state, causing other methods to return nonsense. <sup>[1]</sup>

The `clear()` and `compact()` methods are the logical inverse of `flip()`, restoring the buffer to a "filling" state, with the former also emptying it and the latter maintaining the remaining content.

The general recommendation is to keep any given buffer in a consistent state *always*, with a try/finally; for example:

```
ByteBuffer wrap(ByteBuffer src, ByteBuffer tgt) {
    // assume buffers are *always* kept in the "filling" state
    try {
        src.flip(); // change `src` to "emptying"; assume tgt already filling
        // transfer some or all of `src` to `tgt`
        }
    finally {
        if(src.remaining()) { src.compact(); } // revert `src` to "filling" without discarding remaining data
        else                { src.clear();   } // compact() is (usually) less efficient than clearing
        }
```

#### Typical Finite Cyclic Buffers

Where Java Buffers are most counter-intuitive is due to the fact that most cyclic-buffer implementations are concurrently read/write capable, such that they maintain three values, `head`, `tail` and `capacity` (the last often inferred from the backing array if the language permits it) ***and*** they simply permit the values to wrap. The `head` is where data is read from, and the `tail` is where it is written to. When the end of the underlying array is reached the value of head/tail is simply set to zero (i.e. it cycles around).

When `head == tail`, the buffer is empty. When `inc(tail) == head`, the buffer is full, and the current content length is arrived at by `head <= tail ? (tail - head) : (capacity - head + tail)`. The size of the backing array is generally `capacity+1` such that the the `tail` index is not equal to `head` when the buffer is full (which would be ambiguous without a separate flag).

This makes the internal index handling slightly more complex, but for the benefit not having to flip-flop state and never needing to "compact" the data back to the start of the internal array (though most implementations will reset the start/end indices to zero whenever the buffer is emptied).

Typically, this also translates to a trade-off when reading in that two array copies may be needed; first from `head` to the end of the array and then from beginning of the array to `tail`. Three copy operations may be needed when the target is also a buffer and wraps during write (but the extra copy is hidden within the `put` method).

#### Suppositions

My best guess is that Java defines Buffers in this manner so that all reads and writes to the buffer occur in contiguous blocks. This, presumably, enables downstream/internal optimizations when dealing with things like sockets, memory maps and channels, avoiding intermediary copies needing to be made.

Just guessing here.

#### Notes

[1] Invalid because double flipping will cause the limit to be set to 0, not `capacity`, which will in turn cause `BufferOverflowException` for most internal methods due to `limit - position` being <= 0 or position >= limit. For example:

```
  511       final int nextPutIndex() {                          // package-private
  512           if (position >= limit)
  513               throw new BufferOverflowException();
  514           return position++;
  515       }
  516   
  517       final int nextPutIndex(int nb) {                    // package-private
  518           if (limit - position < nb)
  519               throw new BufferOverflowException();
  520           int p = position;
  521           position += nb;
  522           return p;
  523       }
  524   
  525       /**
  526        * Checks the given index against the limit, throwing an {@link
  527        * IndexOutOfBoundsException} if it is not smaller than the limit
  528        * or is smaller than zero.
  529        */
  530       final int checkIndex(int i) {                       // package-private
  531           if ((i < 0) || (i >= limit))
  532               throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
  533           return i;
  534       }
```

Comment: I just came across [a useful explanation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/XNIO/Accessing+Buffers) in the XNIO manual. It makes similar points.